# python split string if new line exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have simple string which already decoded to utf-8
below is the result string assigned to s variable

```
s = "many simple\n% door needed \n1, but color\n2"
```

i need to split this string using \n{only number 0 to 9} regex

what i already tried is

```
print(s.split(r"\n+[0-9]")) # this is not working.
```

in above string only `\n1` and `\n2` are split should happen but not  `\n%`

so what is correct regex format to spit the string

Comment: You should be using the `re` module for splitting on a regex

Comment: `re.split(r"\n+[0-9]", s)`

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re
s = "many simple\n% door needed \n1, but color\n2"
regex = r"\n[0-9]+"
re.split(regex, s)
```